# Destructor crashing when deleting an array of pointers in C++

Tags: c++, crash, destructor, delete-operator

I made a class named `cell`. Inside this class there is an array of `cell` pointers. The header looks like this:

```
class cell
{       
 public:
  cell();
  cell *c[8];
  void creatcells();
  virtual ~cell();
  ..

}
```

and the `cpp` file looks like this:

```
cell::cell()
{
//ctor
 for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
 {
   c[i]=NULL;
 }

}


void cell::creatcells()

 {
   cell c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8;

   c[0]=&c1;
   c[1]=&c2;
   c[2]=&c3;
   c[3]=&c4;
   c[4]=&c5;
   c[5]=&c6;
   c[6]=&c7;
   c[7]=&c8;
 }

cell::~cell()
{
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        if (c[i]!=NULL)
        {
                    delete c[i];
        }
    }
    delete[] c;

 }
```

But each time the program ends, it crashes, why?
I tried without `if (c[i]!=NULL)`, but this is not helping. Only without the for loop the code ends perfectly, but I know this must be deleted also.
I think I wrote the destructor correctly, didn't I?

Comment: Open program with debugger and it will breaks on crash point

Comment: `cell c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8;` <- all of these are out of scope at the end of the method and the address is not valid.

Comment: None of the variables `c1`, `c2`, etc exist outside the scope of the function `createcells`. So storing pointers to them is going to cause you to have an array full of dangling pointers.

Comment: `delete [] c` is also undefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
void cell::creatcells()
 {
   cell c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8;

   c[0]=&c1;
   c[1]=&c2;
   ...
```

All of the above `cell` objects are automatically destroyed at the end of `createcells()`.So `delete c[i];` in destructor is UB.What you want is

```
 c[0]= new cell();
 c[1]= new cell();
```

Comment: What you *really* want is a `std::vector<cell>` and return value optimisation!

Comment: By doing so , do I have to delete them as I did before? or are they destroyed? I changed the code as you suggested and kept my destructor as before but it crashes again...

Comment: @NoamChai `delete[] c;` You don't need this since you have already deleted all objects in the loop.

Comment: @GauravSehgal `delete[] c` is undefined, so I think "don't need" is an understatement.

Answer (score 4):

You're attempting to dereference pointers to and `delete` variables that had automatic storage duration and are no longer in scope! Didn't your compiler warn you of any of this?

The behaviour of your program is therefore *undefined*.

You only **ever** pair a `delete[]` with a `new[]` and a `delete` with a `new`; although you can delegate the `delete` (and even the `new`<sup>1</sup>) to a managed pointer class like `std::unique_ptr`.

Why don't you refactor to a `std::vector<cell>` and make use of *return value optimisation*?

---

<sup>1</sup>using `std::make_unique`.

Comment: @MartinBonner: Thanks, nicked that.

Answer (score 3):

In `cell::createcells` function the variables are *local* and go out of scope and are destructed once the function returns. Those objects won't exist when you try to delete them. Dereferencing those pointer will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Not to mention that you should only `delete` what you `new`. And since you don't `new` anything doing `delete` on the pointers *again* leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

The simple solution is to use a [vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of *objects*:

```
std::vector<cell> c;
```

Then simply add eight `cell` objects to the vector:

```
void cell::creatcells()
{
    c = std::vector<cell>(8);
}
```

Now the vector will contain eight default-constructed `cell` objects. No need to do anything in the constructor or destructor. In fact with this I recommend you remove the constructor and destructor completely in accordance to [the rule of zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero).